# USB hard drive incremental backup

Tags: usb, incremental-backup

I'm trying to set up a good home data backup solution and am having trouble finding software that would allow me to:

1) Have 2 identical external hard drives. 1 master and 1 slave.
2) Use the master actively to save, modify and delete files.
3) Be able to plug in the slave and run some software that syncs all changes from the master to the slave since the last sync.

Basically create a sort of asynchronous USB raid 1. I'm running OSX 10.8

Comment: Are you looking for an Off The Shelf solution ? Or are you comfortable in rolling your own solution ? Rsync would work nicely in this situation.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm comfortable with the command line, though a simple gui app with a sync button would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're comfortable with terminal, just get [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) and setup your script.
There are also several [GUI apps based on rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Solutions_using_rsync)

Comment: I read up on rsync and then did a little searching. What do you think about this answer?: http://serverfault.com/questions/25329/using-rsync-to-backup-to-an-external-drive/25398#25398

Comment: Yes! If you're OK with terminal, that should be the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

The best tool is [GoodSync for Mac](http://www.goodsync.com/) 
Go through this review of [GoodSync](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/review/goodsync_for_mac_file_synchronization_made_easy).
This is the [SyncToy](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=15155&ei=rc75UpuPMMaNrQfmjIGgBQ&usg=AFQjCNHIZAFL5XkV6srYbMvaYau6X5yYaw) alternative for mac.